# Swift / iOS: Analyzing (lldb) crash, PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, lldb, taplytics

I am using PayPal iOS SDK in my Swift project.

When I dismiss the standard `PayPalPaymentViewController` using the BarButtonItem in the NavigationBar, I am getting the following error in console:

`(lldb)` in green color, nothing else.

I have tried typing `bt` in console, below the output:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x271b32, 0x00000001951fc0b4 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 20, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1625f6c90)
    frame #0: 0x00000001951fc0b4 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 20
    frame #1: 0x0000000100215e0c MyApp`-[UIBarButtonItem(TLBarButtonItem) tl_barButtonAction:] + 32
    frame #2: 0x000000010032c1d8 MyApp`-[UIBarButtonItem(PPZebraAnalyticsWidgetCategories) ppZebraAnalyticsWidgetDidTrigger] + 200
    frame #3: 0x0000000100215ea4 MyApp`-[UIBarButtonItem(TLBarButtonItem) tl_barButtonAction:] + 184
    frame #4: 0x000000018927d418 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    frame #5: 0x000000018927d418 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    frame #6: 0x000000018926652c UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
    frame #7: 0x000000018927cdb4 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 592
    frame #8: 0x000000018927ca40 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 700
    frame #9: 0x0000000189275f94 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 684
    frame #10: 0x000000018924968c UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
    frame #11: 0x00000001894e860c UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14992
    frame #12: 0x0000000189247bf4 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1616
    frame #13: 0x0000000184a529ec CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #14: 0x0000000184a51c90 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
    frame #15: 0x0000000184a4fd40 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 712
    frame #16: 0x000000018497d0a4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    frame #17: 0x000000018db175a4 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
    frame #18: 0x00000001892aeaa4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
  * frame #19: 0x00000001005edd50 MyApp`top_level_code + 76 at AppDelegate.swift:17
    frame #20: 0x00000001005edd90 MyApp`main + 48 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #21: 0x0000000195852a08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

I am clueless about how to interpret the above backtrace.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to find out more what exactly is causing the error? If I need to provide more information, please let me know, I'll happily add it.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: the thread you're showing is indicating that you're trying to access something that your code expects but isn't actually there. the debugger provides a lot of extraneous info, but there are two important things in your trace: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS always means your calling something that doesn't exist (not instantiated or has been released) and the statements at the top is the code run most recently on the main queue. So there's a problem with what your tl_barbuttonAction is doing or calling. add an exception breakpoint and check out the state of your variables/objects just before the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work @ Taplytics!

I'm sorry for the confusion, but the issue has been resolved in v2.1.40 of the Taplytics iOS SDK.

Because you're using Segment, you'll need to update their SDK to >= v1.10.3, which will automatically update Taplytics to the correct version.

Please feel free to reach out to our team if you're having any trouble after you make the update!

Comment: Thanks again Aaron, updating the Taplytics SDK to v2.1.40 indeed solved this issue for us.

Comment: Glad to hear that all is now well!

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

Please see this issue: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/251  -- it looks like you and that developer are having the same problem using the Taplytics library simultaneously with the PayPal iOS Library.

Please check with Taplytics first (in case they have already worked this out with that developer), and then join the discussion in the above issue in the PayPal-iOS-SDK repo with what you learn, or for further assistance.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your reply. I am indeed using Taplytics SDK - I'll check the link you mentioned and hopefully figure this out. Thanks again, and I'll post here as soon as I know more!

Comment: I have just contacted the folks at Taplytics, let's see if we can get this sorted out. In any case, I'll update my thread here and/or on github as soon as we fixed this. Thanks for being so active here and on github, it's awesome!